# Concat of two list using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have two list list1 and list2

List1 contains

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

List2 contains

```
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

I want following list using LINQ

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

Comment: I am using this                                              

var list1 = new List<tst>
                            {
                                new tst {Id = 1, Val = "a"},
                                new tst {Id = 2, Val = "b"},
                                new tst {Id = 3, Val = "c"},
                                new tst {Id = 4, Val = "d"}
                            };

            var list2 = new List<tst>
                            {new tst {Id = 3, Val = "c"}, new tst {Id = 4, Val = "d"}, new tst {Id = 5, Val = "e"}};

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
List1.Concat(List2.Where(l2 => !List1.Contains(l2))).ToList()
```

Comment: from where l1 comes. Wrong Answer

Answer (score 12):

Since I don't see this answer here i'll post it...

The best way to remove duplicates while merging two lists together is [Enumerable.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var foo = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
var bar = new List<char> { 'c', 'd', 'e' };

var result = foo.Union(bar).ToList();
```

The rest of the answers work, but Linq has a built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Lst = List1.Concat(List2.Where(l2 => List1.All(x => x.Id != l2.Id))).ToList();
```