# add generic list item to another existing list item using c#

Tags: c#

I have a generic list filled with items. In this list I have one column which is unique (like an ID). And I have another generic list with other items and the same ID column. This is the way I fill the items to the lists:

```
foreach (string s in l1)
{
    GridViewSource src = new GridViewSource();
    src.test = "id" + s;

    list.Add(src);
}

foreach (string s in l2)
{
    GridViewSource src = new GridViewSource();
    src.test = "id" + s;
    src.test2 = "somerandomtext" + s;

    list2.Add(src);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to add items from `list2` to `list` if they have the same ID. So it should add an item from `list2` with the ID "id3" to the item "id3" of `list`. Like merging. I don't want to add them to the bottom of the list or insert them between the items. I tried `Concat` method but it's just adding the items add the end of the list:

```
list = list.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

I try to explain it another way:

My `list` looks like this:

```
[0] => test = "id1", test2 = ""
[1] => test = "id2", test2 = ""
[2] => test = "id3", test2 = ""
[3] => test = "id4", test2 = ""
[4] => test = "id5", test2 = ""
```

And my `list2` looks like this:

```
[0] => test = "id1", test2 = "somerandomtext1"
[1] => test = "id2", test2 = "somerandomtext2"
[2] => test = "id3", test2 = "somerandomtext3"
```

**And when I merge the lists, it should look like this:**

```
[0] => test = "id1", test2 = "somerandomtext1"
[1] => test = "id2", test2 = "somerandomtext2"
[2] => test = "id3", test2 = "somerandomtext3"
[3] => test = "id4", test2 = ""
[4] => test = "id5", test2 = ""
```

But it looks like this:

```
[0] => test = "id1", test2 = ""
[1] => test = "id2", test2 = ""
[2] => test = "id3", test2 = ""
[3] => test = "id4", test2 = ""
[4] => test = "id5", test2 = ""
[5] => test = "id1", test2 = "somerandomtext1"
[6] => test = "id2", test2 = "somerandomtext2"
[7] => test = "id3", test2 = "somerandomtext3"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: *" I don't want to add them to the bottom of the list or insert them between the items."* Then where do you want to add them?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to explain. I'll edit my question, 1sec

Comment: Why dont you short the list?

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523097/concat-of-two-list-using-linq ?

Comment: Refer to the accepted answer for [LINQ Join 2 List<T>s][1] You have same problem statement. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723985/linq-join-2-listts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to merge on the item level, not on the list level.

I'm sure there is some clever way to do it using Linq,
but I don't have too much experience with Linq, so I can suggest a simple nested for loops:

```
foreach (GridViewSource src1 in list1)
{
    foreach(GridViewSource src2 in list2)
    {
        if(src1.test1 == src2.test1)
        {
            src1.test2 = src2.test2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a custom comparer:

```
public class MyComparer: IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T o1,T o2)
    {
        // They are the same object
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(o1, o2))
            return true;
        // They are not the same
        if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
            return false;
        // They have the same ID
        return o1.test1.Equals(o2.test1);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(X x)
    {
        return x.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then use it in the call:

```
list = list.Union(list2, new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

**I have not tested this code.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the wrong path using a `List<T>` for this, a [`Dictionary<K, V>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is better suited for this situation.

Then you could do:

```
dict[src.test] = src;
```

And in the second code, where you need to update (or add) an item:

```
GridViewSource outsrc;
if (dict.TryGetValue(src.test, out outsrc))
{
    // items exists: update
    outsrc.test2 = src.test2;
}
else
{
    // item doesn't exist: add
    dict[src.test] = src;
}
```